# Export Eventlogs and send email

Tags: powershell, event-viewer

[image]I have written a script to export specific Eventvwr logs based on Source and the script is working as expected, but i am trying to cut short the message form the Eventvwr, i dont to print entire message on the mail.

I am attaching the output of my code below

```
#
#  This script exports consolidated and filtered event logs to CSV
#

#Application error and critical eventlogs for specific EventID:
#Email Details
$FromAddress = 'abc.com'
$ToAddress = '123.com'
$SmtpServer = 'xyz.com'

Set-Variable -Name EventAgeDays -Value 4    #we will take events for the latest 7 days
Set-Variable -Name CompArr -Value @("abcedf.com")   # replace it with your server names
Set-Variable -Name LogNames -Value @("Application")  # Checking app and system logs
Set-Variable -Name EventTypes -Value @("Information")  # Loading only Errors and Warnings
Set-Variable -Name ExportFolder -Value "C:\xxx\"
Set-Variable -Name Source -Value @("123", "111")

$el_c = @()   #consolidated error log
$now=get-date
$startdate=$now.adddays(-$EventAgeDays)
$ExportFile=$ExportFolder + "Out" + $now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd---hh-mm-ss") + ".csv"  # we cannot use standard delimiteds like ":"

foreach($comp in $CompArr)
{
  foreach($log in $LogNames)
  {
    foreach ($src in $Source)
    {
    Write-Host Processing $comp\$log
    $el = get-eventlog -ComputerName $comp -log $log -After $startdate -EntryType $EventTypes -Source $src -Newest 1 -InstanceId 30000 
    $el_c += $el  #consolidating
  #}
#}
$el_sorted = $el_c | Sort-Object TimeGenerated    #sort by time
Write-Host Exporting to $ExportFile
}
} 
} 
$out = $el_sorted|Select MachineName, EntryType, TimeGenerated, Source, EventID, Message #| Export-CSV $ExportFile -NoTypeInfo  #EXPORT
Write-Host Done!

$msgBody = $out
Send-MailMessage -from $FromAddress -to $ToAddress -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Subject "TL Stage Ingester Status from $CompArr $startdate" -Body ( $msgBody | Out-String)
```

Comment: You are trying to not send the entire email ? I mean if you only want X hunk you can always cut with ```.length``` Can you expand what you want more?

Comment: i have attached the output as a image i just want those line from my entire message

Comment: ..But that still does not show what it it you want to cut short..

Comment: from the eventlog output we will have the entire message with all the details, but i want to cut short only the above part in the image from the entire output and send it via mail